# How would I prevent copying of my itch.io published game?

Tags: copying

I have recently made a page on itch.io, I am wondering how I would be able to prevent people from copying the files and sending it instead of paying the $20. In other words, I want to make sure that the person who tries to run the launcher / installer has purchased the game from itch.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is the same as mojang, create yourgameaccount@gmail.com and yourgameusertag. That way you can prevent maybe. Try to do like minecraft where you require registered account to play the game.

Comment: Hm, Good idea! Still open to hear ideas from others.

Comment: yeah sure , here to help